# Holoview, Panel, Bokeh versions for use without import errors

Tags: python, debugging, bokeh, dependency-management, holoviews

```
Version numbers:
Package                        Version      Editable project location
------------------------------ ------------ --------------------------------------
bokeh                          2.4.1
holoviews                      1.14.0       /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages
panel                          0.12.4
```

My Jupyter notebook doesn't want to let me call `import panel`, with this error:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bokeh/embed/server.py in <module>
     32 
     33 # Bokeh imports
---> 34 from ..core.templates import AUTOLOAD_REQUEST_TAG, FILE
     35 from ..resources import DEFAULT_SERVER_HTTP_URL
     36 from ..util.serialization import make_id

ImportError: cannot import name 'AUTOLOAD_REQUEST_TAG' from 'bokeh.core.templates' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bokeh/core/templates.py)
```

Ok so

```
user@docker:/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bokeh/core# ls
__init__.py  __pycache__  _templates  enums.py  has_props.py  json_encoder.py  properties.py  property  property_mixins.py  query.py  templates.py  types.py  validation

user@docker:/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bokeh/core# cd _templates/
user@docker:/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bokeh/core/_templates# ls
autoload_js.js     autoload_request_tag.html  css_resources.html  doc_nb_js.js  js_resources.html  notebook_load.html  root_div.html    try_run.js
autoload_nb_js.js  autoload_tag.html          doc_js.js           file.html     macros.html        plot_div.html       script_tag.html
```

Does that underscore have something to do with it?

```
user@docker:/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bokeh/core# grep AUTO /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bokeh/core/templates.py
.. bokeh-jinja:: bokeh.core.templates.AUTOLOAD_JS
.. bokeh-jinja:: bokeh.core.templates.AUTOLOAD_NB_JS
.. bokeh-jinja:: bokeh.core.templates.AUTOLOAD_REQUEST_TAG
.. bokeh-jinja:: bokeh.core.templates.AUTOLOAD_TAG
    'AUTOLOAD_JS',
    'AUTOLOAD_NB_JS',
    'AUTOLOAD_REQUEST_TAG',
    'AUTOLOAD_TAG',
AUTOLOAD_JS = _env.get_template("autoload_js.js")
AUTOLOAD_NB_JS = _env.get_template("autoload_nb_js.js")
AUTOLOAD_TAG = _env.get_template("autoload_tag.html")
AUTOLOAD_REQUEST_TAG = _env.get_template("autoload_request_tag.html")
```

Looks like it's there.  I tried making a copy of `/_templates` as `/templates` but it didn't help.

Could anyone either send me some version numbers that work together, or, let me know how I might fix the import error?

Thanks

Comment: Having seen this many, many times now over the years, the issue is very likely that you have an environment mixup, and are running the notebook from a different environment that has an older version of Bokeh installed. You can check by running `import bokeh; print(bokeh.__version__)` in the notebook. The `AUTOLOAD_REQUEST_TAG` was added way back in version 2.0.

Comment: Also note that even if the reported versions are accurate, bokeh 2.4.1 and panel 0.12.4 are current versions, while holoviews 1.14.0 is six versions out of date, so I'd try updating holoviews to the current release of 1.14.6.

Comment: Ok, interesting, print version shows bokeh 0.12.15.  So why's it saying "Requirement already satisfied: bokeh==2.4.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.4.1)" ? (pip list shows 2.4.1) How might i resolve this? (I'm in Jupyter in a docker but have access to the command line).

Comment: I'd call `which jupyter` to see which environment you're starting jupyterlab from, then use `conda list` to examine all the contents of your env and make sure bokeh and the others are up to date and in the same env as jupyter. Also, try scrapping conda and starting over :) that's necessary every once in a long while...

Comment: Ok thanks, I restarted the kernel, which I am sure I did before, but it fixed itself now and shows 2.4.1.  Who knows. Thanks for the help